# XSLT Batch Processing

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, batch-processing

I have the following XML structure:

```
<School>
  <SchoolInfo>
    <SchoolName>The Big School</SchoolName>
    <Opened>2008</Opened>
    <SchoolID>SCH1122</SchoolID>
    <Geograpics>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <PostCode>ZZ11 1ZZ</PostCode>
    </Geographics>
  </SchoolInfo>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
    <Class>12B</Class>
    <Age>16</Age>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
    <Class>09A</Class>
    <Age>17</Age>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Joe</Name>
    <LastName>Blogs</LastName>
    <Class>13A</Class>
    <Age>15</Age>
  </Pupil>
</School>
```

If my XML structure were to contain say.. 400 Pupils and I wanted to process them in batches of 50 and write to seperate PSV's for each 50 pupils, so the first 50, then 50-100, then 100-150 and so on and write each batch to a new file.. Can this be done using XSLT or would it have to be programatic?

I now have the code to process to PSV etc im just being held up on how to process in batch as I quite frankly haven't a clue!

--
PSV: Pipe Seperated Values

```
SCH1122|London|Tom|12B|16
SCH1122|London|Steve|09A|17
SCH1122|London|Joe|13A|15
```

The code used to convert the XML is as follows:

```
private string PerformTransformation(string FilePath)
{
    string fullXsltFile;

    if (chkDateIncrement.Checked == false)
        fullXsltFile = Resources.XSLTTest; // Resources.XSLT;
    else
        fullXsltFile = Resources.XSLTTest;

    XmlDocument xsltTransformDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xsltTransformDocument.LoadXml(fullXsltFile);

    FileInfo xmlFileInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    string outputFile = CreateXmlOutputFileName(xmlFileInfo);

    // load the Xslt with any settings
    XslCompiledTransform transformation = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, false);
    settings.EnableScript = true;
    transformation.Load(xsltTransformDocument, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath))
    {
       using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
       {
           transformation.Transform(reader, null, stream);
           stream.Close();
       }
       reader.Close();
    }
    return outputFile;
}
```

I am also using the microsofts processer with VS2010 so sadly does not support v2.0, therefore would have to be v1.0 XSLT

Preferably a method of doing this with the standard xslt1.0 build would be best as getting in additional components is not the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Please, provide the exact wanted result. Also, not everybody could *guess* what PSV means -- my current guess is "Pipe-Separated Values". Please, edit the question and provide this necessary information.

Comment: And, of course, XSLT is "programmatic" :)

Comment: I'm after then ability to batch process the data (eg 400 pupils and only have 50 to a .txt file, so make 8 files) not the actual output structure as you gave, as I stated in the paragraph below the example XML.

Comment: There is *no mention* of creating different files in the question. Please, edit the question and add this missing requirement. Also, creating more than one output file isn't possible in pure XSLT 1.0. You will need either an XSLT 2.0 processor, or an XSLT processor with an EXSLT implementation of the `exslt:document` extension element, or you will need to write your own extension function. Please, specify in the question which of these possible solutions you are after.

Comment: edited as asked, would prefer the extensive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It isn't possible with pure XSLT 1.0 to produce more than one result document**.

To do so, you will need to call an extension function (that you'll have to write) for saving an element in a separate file.

You need to read your MSDN documentation on **[how to write an extension function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx)**.

**The transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pBatchLength" select="2"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vId" select="/*/SchoolInfo/SchoolID"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLoc" select="/*/SchoolInfo/Geographics/Location"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Pupil[position() mod $pBatchLength = 1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Pupil">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfBatch">
    <batch>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="inbatch" select=
        ". | following-sibling::Pupil[not(position() > $pBatchLength -1)]"/>
    </batch>
   </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select=
      "my:writeResult($vrtfBatch, ceiling(position() div $pBatchLength))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Pupil" mode="inbatch">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('&#xA;', $vId, '|', $vLoc, '|', Name, '|', Class, '|', Age)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The desired length of a "batch" is specified in the external/global parameter `$pBatchLength` and its default value (for our small demo-example is defined as `2`).
2. All `Pupil` elements that start a new batch are processed (in anonymous mode).
3. If necessary the batch is wrapped in a `batch` element (if not, this code may be deleted). Then all `Pupil` element comprising the current batch are processed in `"inbatch"` mode and the necessary CSV input is generated for each of them.
4. The iutput is captured in a variable named  `$vrtfBatch`. The extension function (which you have to write) `my:writeResult` is called with parameters: `$vrtfBatch` and the sequence number for this batch. The extension function has to create a new file (using the seq. no, for the filename) and write there the contents.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind what happens here at a high level?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [eXtensible Stylesheets (xslt)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Comment: do you happen to know the Microsoft namespace for the redirect as that is written for a specific processor

Comment: Actually, there is nothing directly similar to "redirect" in msxml, but you can write a Javascript method which accepts a result-tree-fragment as a parameter, and serializes it using
the methods available in Microsoft's DOM implementation.

Comment: Sadly I don't know a thing about javascript so that rules that one out